# "clean" error with CUDA 5.5 in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have been using Visual Studio 2010 Express for my CUDA-related development.  Recently, I upgraded from CUDA 5.0 to 5.5.  When I did so, I discovered what is seemingly an odd bug: whenever I go to clean (or to rebuild) my VS project, I get an error related to nvcc:

```
nvcc : fatal error : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual Studio. Only the versions 2008, 2010, and 2012 are supported
```

I get this same error on multiple independent projects whenever I try to clean them.  The error goes away if I use Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

I was wondering if anyone else has come across this error, and, if so, are there any workarounds (other than switching to VS 2010 Professional)?

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: I get similar errors even with Cuda Toolkit 5.0 and upgrading to Pro did not help. Really puzzled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [release notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) for CUDA 5.5, Visual Studio 2010 Express is not supported. The supported versions of Visual Studio are:

```
Compiler          IDE
Visual C++ 11.0   Visual Studio 2012
Visual C++ 11.0   Visual Studio 2012 Express (32-bit)
Visual C++ 10.0   Visual Studio 2010
Visual C++ 9.0    Visual Studio 2008
```

Comment: Want to emphasize that this error only occurs when VS 2010 Express is asked to *Clean* or *Rebuild*.  But *Build* still works and the executable works just fine.

Comment: how do you make sure you are Building, and not Cleaning or Rebuilding from the command line?