# Supported Windows compilers in CUDA

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I am a complete novice CUDA programmer trying to get started, and I am encountering the issue mentioned here with version 5.5

["clean" error with CUDA 5.5 in Visual Studio 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140503/clean-error-with-cuda-5-5-in-visual-studio-2010-express)

Can anyone confirm that this is an issue with version 5.5 only? Is there an earlier version that I can install e.g. 5.0, that will allow nvcc to work with the Visual Studio 10.0 Express version compiler under 64-bit Windows 7?

Comment: These [Release Notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) exclude the possibility of using Visual Studio 2010 Express also for CUDA 5.0, see Table 5.

Comment: That's very strange. In the thread I cited, the OP seemed to say that he had no difficulty before upgrading to 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a late answer provided here to remove this question from the unanswered list.

From the **NVIDIA CUDA TOOLKIT V5.0 Release Notes**, Section 5.1, Table 1

**Supported Windows Compilers (32-bit and 64-bit)**

```
Compiler          IDE
Visual C++ 10.0   Visual Studio 2010
Visual C++ 9.0    Visual Studio 2008
```

From the **NVIDIA CUDA TOOLKIT V5.5 Release Notes**, Table 2

**Windows Compilers Supported in CUDA 5.5**

```
Compiler          IDE
Visual C++ 11.0   Visual Studio 2012
Visual C++ 11.0   Visual Studio 2012 Express (32-bit)
Visual C++ 10.0   Visual Studio 2010
Visual C++ 9.0    Visual Studio 2008
```

From the **NVIDIA CUDA GETTING STARTED GUIDE FOR MICROSOFT WINDOWS for CUDA 6.0**

**Windows Compiler Support in CUDA 6.0**

```
Compiler          IDE
Visual C++ 11.0   Visual Studio 2012 Express
Visual C++ 10.0   Visual Studio 2010 
Visual C++ 9.0    Visual Studio 2008
```

In all the above releases, there is no support for Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Comment: I accept this answer since it is true officially. However, I footnote that upgrading to Professional did not fix the issue. Eventually, I was able to compile reliably only by installing NVIDIA's build template. With the template, I conjecture that nvcc might work even with VS 2010 Express, regardless of whether it is officially supported, but I did not try.

Comment: @MattJ I'm answering this question to remove it from the unanswered list. I have also tried to make your post more searchable so that other novice users could more easily find it. There is no problem in using CUDA 5.0, 5.5 or 6.0 Visual Studio Professional 2010: this is my direct experience. I don't know what do you mean by _installing NVIDIA's build template_. If you refer to the needof starting a new project by using the provided template, then it would mean that there is some mis-setting when you start the new project without the template, see http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/109.

Comment: "@JackOLantern" Yes, I'm sure there was an issue with the settings. However, I found that only through the template was getting the settings right easy/reliable. Moreover, maybe with the correct settings, Express will work as well, even if not supported. I have not tried your link, but (a) it doesn't seem to cover compiling for 64 bit (b) I have a lot of unremovable junk from a previous installation of Express. I need to be able to navigate around that as well.